# Is this the right tense for lay?

Tags: grammar

The play's set was completely painted, but Jennifer laid the freshly-painted board face down on the floor.

Comment: Yes. It's the past tense of the regular transitive [causative verb _lay_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf). You can tell it's transitive because it has a direct object noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes. It's the past tense of the regular transitive [causative verb lay](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf). You can tell it's transitive because it has a direct object noun phrase.

--[@John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276645/is-this-the-right-tense-for-lay#comment611331_276645)